# Find triplets such that their sum is divisible by 3. Can this be solved in O(n^2) or any other optimization?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
// your code goes here
vector<int> arr={0,2,3,4};
int count=0;

int n = arr.size();
for(int i=0;i<n-2;i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1;j<n-1;j++)
    {
        for(int k=j+1;k<n;k++)
        {
            if(i+1==j && j+1==k)
            {
                if((arr[i]+arr[j]+arr[k])%3==0)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
cout<<count<<" ";
return 0;
}
```

This solution is O(n^3) for generating triplets whose average is divisible by 3 and elements of triplets must be consecutive.How to optimize this solution?

Comment: If the elements must be consecutive, then there are only `O(n)` triplets to look at. You don't need nested loops - just run one loop and have it look at `arr[i]`, `arr[i+1]` and `arr[i+2]`

Comment: *"elements of triplets must be consecutive"* Do you mean it literally (`0 <= i < n - 2`, `j = i + 1` and `k = i + 2` -> O(n) algortihm) or the actual constraint is relaxed enough to consider all the possible *unique* triplets (`0<= i < j < k < n` -> I can think of an O(n^2) algorithm)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Separate your numbers in three tables according to their value modulo 3 (their sizes are n0,n1 and n2). This is o(n)
2. the triplets answer to your questions are:

   a) three numbers with the same value modulo 3
   o(C(3,n0)+C(3,n1)+C(3,n2)) = o(n^3) max if n0=n1=n2=n/3

   b) one number equal 0, the other 1 the third 2 and permutations
   o(n0*n1*n2) = o(n^3) max if n0=n1=n2=n/3

This is o(n^3) because the number of solutions is o(n^3) worst case.